# navigating on the check-boxes using tab key and selecting them using space key

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am using the check-boxes wrapped inside the label tag and also using another label to display a custom icon and hover effect for the check-box. It is working fine using the mouse i.e I can select the check-box using mouse.

But now I have to navigate through these check-boxes using the tab key and make them select-able using the space key. I tried by adding the tabindex to both input field and label tag but none of them seems to working.

here is the code snippet that we are using

`<label for="checkbox1">
    <input class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" tabindex="1"/>
        <label class="check-label" for="checkbox1"> Health Check </label>
</label>`

how can I navigate on these check-boxes using tab key and make a selection using space key?

Answer (score 0):

You're probaly looking for a solution like this:

```
<label for="checkbox1">
    <input class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" tabindex="0"/>
    <span>Health Check</span>
</label>
<br />
<label for="checkbox2">
    <input class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" tabindex="0"/>
    <span>Health Check #2</span>
</label>
<br />
<label for="checkbox3">
    <input class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" tabindex="0"/>
    <span>Health Check #3</span>
</label>
```

The key points are to use only one wrapping `label` and then `tabindex=0`.

Demo: http://cssdeck.com/labs/oeyqxhhz

Comment: your layout is correct for the functionality is what I'm saying.

Comment: True about tabindex. `tabindex=0` is meant for elements that doesn't have default functionality from browser (like `<div>`).

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  If I have a "name" on all the checkboxes that are the same, I do not get a value back from the checkbox I used the spacebar to toggle it with.  If I use the mouse, then it works.